# Power Series / Taylor Expansion of $\frac{1}{\left(1-t^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

The question:

$\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\:=\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_nt^n$

The question asks for what is $a_n$

These are the steps I've done:

$\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\:=\:\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1+t}{1+t}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\:=\:\frac{1+t}{\left(1-t^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\:=\:\left(1+t\right)\left(1-t^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

I know I need to expand $\left(1-t^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ to then multiply it with $\left(1+t\right)$ formally and get a result. However, I do not know how to get from $\frac{1}{1-t}\:=\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:t^n\:\rightarrow \:\frac{1}{1-t^2}\:=\:\sum \:_{n=0}^{\infty \:}\:t^{2n}\:\rightarrow \:\frac{1}{\left(1-t^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\:=\:?$
or even if I am in the right track.

I appreciate any help! :)

Comment: I forgot to add that the question asks for $a_n$

Comment: You can - and probably should - edit your question to include what is *the* question

Comment: @Dzoooks See Alexandre Filho's comment saying he "forgot to add that the question asks for ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand $x\mapsto \sqrt{1-x}$ into

$$\sqrt{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n \binom{1/2}{n}.$$
It is not very hard to prove that this is the correct Taylor expansion. Then, differentiate both sides of the equation and finally substitute $ x = t^2$.

Comment: I like this answer fine, but if you’re willing to use $\binom{1/2}n$, I don’t see why you don’t just recommend $\sum_0^\infty(-x^2)^n\binom{-1/2}n$ .

Comment: @Lubin fair point. I have no good reason for doing it like this, other than that I thought that the expansion of $x \mapsto \sqrt{1-x}$ is fairly well-known, possibly more so than the binomial theorem for non-integer powers.

Comment: It was fairly easy to figure out the expansion of $x \mapsto \sqrt{1-x}$ actually, using a quick search was more than enough to find another thread